# Why can't I access private members of the outer class from the inner class when nesting classes?

Tags: c++, class, private, inner-classes, access-specifier

```
class X
{
    int Xi;

    class Y
    {
        int Yi;

        void func()
        {
            X x;
            x.Xi = 5;
        }
    };

    void func()
    {
        Y y;
        y.Yi = 5;
    //  ^^^^ 'X::Y::Yi': cannot access private member declared in class 'X::Y'
    }
};
```

I was learning about the Memento pattern and in the book I read, it was stated that one of the ways of achieving the pattern is by writing the `Memento` class inside the `Originator` class so that only the `Originator` can have access to the private members of the `Memento` class. When I tried to apply this method I got an error telling me that the private member is inaccessible. I know that I can use the keyword `friend` and that will give me access to the private members. Also I know that I can access the outer class's private members from the inner class. But why can't the inner class access the private members of the inner class?

I can do this in java for example:

```
public class X {

    int Xi;

    public class Y
    {
        private int Yi;

        public void func()
        {
            X x = new X();
            x.Xi = 5;
        }
    }

    public void func()
    {
        Y y = new Y();
        y.Yi = 5;
    }
}
```

Why is it not doable in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the title of your question, what you are trying to do on the line `y.Yi = 5;` is access a private member of the ***inner*** class from the body of the ***outer*** class. This you cannot do, because the `Yi` member is *private* - so it can only be accessed from inside its class.

On the other hand, the line`x.Xi = 5;` does indeed access a private member of the ***outer*** class from the ***inner*** class; this, you are allowed to do, because your inner `Y` class is part of the outer `X` class.

One way to get round this is to declare the `X::func()` function a *friend* of `class Y`; however, you will then need to provide a 'prototype' of that function *before* you make that declaration, and you would thus need to make the actual *definition* of the function *outside* the class body (it must come after the `class Y` declaration, as it uses an object of that class):

```cpp
class X {
private: // Even without this line, members are private by default!
    int Xi;
    void func(); // Just a declaration (prototype) - wwwe still need the definition
    class Y {
    private:
        int Yi;
        void func() {
            X x;
            x.Xi = 5;
        }
        friend void X::func();
    };
};

void X::func() { // This is the actual definition of the function.
    Y y;
    y.Yi = 5;
}
```

Comment: What if we make the variable as "friend" in case of trying to access the private members?

Comment: I've updated the quesion. I can do it in java but not in c++. What is the reason for not making this possible in C++?

Comment: @LinuXMan Yes - you could allow the access to happen by declaring `class Y` as a `friend` of `class X` - just put the line `friend class X;` somewhere inside the definition of `class Y`.

Comment: @StackExchange123 C++ and Java are different languages and have different rules. I don't really 'do' Java, so I can't speak for why the code you have added works.

Comment: @LinuXMan Or you could just make the X::func()` function a friend - see edit.

Comment: @StackExchange123 You can try the code I have given: maybe C++ is inherently less **friendly** than Java is?  ‎

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah I've just seen your edited code. That used as a friend function to access the subclass member. I've just answered another way to do so by just making the class members public.